# MS word algorithm for text justification

Tags: algorithm, ms-word

What's the algorithm that MS word uses to justify text. 
 Also is there a way to specify a certain width for your document in ms word so that each line contains max that many characters. Basically justifying it to a fixed width. 
 I have seen it spacing out evenly words in a line.
It looks like it does a greedy approach

Comment: Kinda tough question...don't think we'd be able to figure out how MS Word in particular justifies text unless we do quite a bit of testing or reverse engineering. On the other hand, if you just need a text justification algorithm it'd be as easy as picking the third google search from "justify text algorithm": https://www.malikbrowne.com/blog/text-justification-coding-question

Comment: The native Word justification routine expands only the space between words to fit the column width. If you have a document that is Word 2010 format or earlier, you can apply a compatibility option (File>Options>Advanced>Compatibility options>Do full justification the way WordPerfect 6.x for Windows does) that adds space between letters as well as words. It's a much better look. Since character widths vary, it's not realistic to space by a fixed number of characters. You could get close with a monospaced font.

Comment: Is there an online version of Microsoft word for experimentation purposes. I don't have a license I am not sure if they provide any such thing or some other online doc thing which has the same justification algorithm as the microsoft word

Comment: Use a fixed width font?

Comment: This is not a programming question and, as such, is off-topic for Stack Overflow. Questions on general usage of Microsoft Word should be asked on an appropriate end-use forum (e.g., MS Answers).

Comment: This question is off-topic. https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic It should not be answered here. Try Super User https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/microsoft-word or Microsoft Answers http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/msoffice_word, Word Forum http://www.msofficeforums.com/word/ or ITPro https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/topics/office-word-itpro.html. (Please do not post in more than one.)